# Calling MySQL stored procedure from PHP is not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Using MySQL 5.6, I tried to run a SQL query from PHP (PDO), but the results were different than when running from MySQL Workbench, so I eventually gave up and wrote a stored procedure instead, which I again call from PHP. However, I am getting the same invalid results :-(
To prove the results were different, I changed the code to just return the count of records.
The stored procedure can be seen here...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id, date, 
            @var_num := if(@var_id = id, @var_num + 1, 1) as row_number,
            @var_id := id 
        FROM `data`
        GROUP BY id, date
        HAVING row_number <= 2
        ORDER BY id DESC, date DESC
    ) s2
ORDER BY id ASC, date DESC;
END
```

When I run the stored procedure from MYSQL Workbench, it returns 7,328, which is correct, but when I run it from PHP using...

```
$pdo = $this->database->getPdo();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('CALL test()');
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The result is 4,925,479. If I try to return the actual data then it runs out of memory!
What am I doing wrong as I presumed that the stored procedure would run the same, wherever it was called from?

Comment: PHP has a limit of how much memory it can use. If you are trying to return a huge dataset with lots of information it might be using too much PHP memory, so you'll either need to increase the PHP limit within the php.ini file or return a subset of your data in chunks so PHP doesn't have to store it all in memory.

I would guess the 4,925,479 number is the amount of bytes PHP tried to use for RAM

Comment: I presumed (again) that the 4,925,479 was the number of rows that it was trying to return, which is wrong. There is about 5 million records in the table in question, but running it from MySQL Workbench returns 7,328 rows, which is correct, and only takes a few seconds.

Comment: Is that the real code? You order by `id` and `date` but the only column is `count(*)`. I can't tell for sure but it's probably related to session variables lifetime. Perhaps you need to initialise your variables first.

Comment: @Álvaro González, yes I replaced the original code with count(*) as a test because it was just running out of memory, due to returning too many results. I also think that it is related to the variables, but I haven't found any useful information yet as to what the problem is. I have tried various changes, but nothing seems to make a difference :-(

Comment: But, does it make any difference if you initialise your variables first? As in e.g. `@var_num := 0` (or whatever the exact syntax is)?

Comment: You have not defined this procedure correctly. You need to indicate that you are returning a result set using an `OUT` parameter. Also `ORDER BY id ASC, date DESC` would be causing an error, as those columns don't exist. There's no need to prepare and execute a query with no bound variables, but you should be checking for an error result when the query is run instead of blindly doing a `fetchAll()`.

Comment: @Álvaro González, I initialized the variables in the stored procedure, but this did not make a difference. However, after several more hours :-( I did get it to work by initializing the variables in a CROSS JOIN :-)

Comment: @miken32, I had removed the id and date as a test, whilst I just returned the count(*), because otherwise the procedure caused memory issues :-(
As mentioned above, I finally fixed it by adding a CROSS JOIN.

Answer (score -1):

Although the stored procedure may not be complete, I will show the updated procedure here, that now works for me. Hopefully this will save someone else from a lot of wasted time :-(

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id, date, 
            @var_num := if(@var_id = id, @var_num + 1, 1) as row_number,
            @var_id := id 
        FROM `data`
        CROSS JOIN (select @var_num := 0, @var_id := 0) cj 
        GROUP BY id, date
        HAVING row_number <= 2
        ORDER BY id DESC, date DESC
    ) s2
ORDER BY id ASC, date DESC;
END
```